# Why putting colon before variable name is a valid code in js?

Tags: javascript, variables

Example:

```js
let :test = "Hello";
console.log(test);
```

This code doesn't throw any error. Why?

Comment: The code is interpreted as `let: test = "Hello";` the `:` is part of `let` which is a **label** here. You can tell that this is not a variable declaration because the console prints the value you assign. If it was a variable declaration it would print `undefined`. Also have running the code, `test` exists (not `:test`) and has the value `"Hello"`. Same effect: `foo :bar = "Hello";`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the answer! One more question. Why in this case it throws an error? (without strict mode) const :test = "Hello"; console.log(test);

Comment: `let` is not a reserved word in non-strict mode: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words, which means it can be used as variable name and other places. E.g. `var let = 42;` is valid in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you actually have a label https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

If you were in strict mode, it would have thrown an error.

```
let: // <-- label
  test = "hello
```